# How do I export a C++ project on a windows PC and run it on a Linux one?

Tags: c++, linux

So I have just started learning C++ and I want to test my first program on Linux. Here is my program:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#define ANSI_COLOR_RED     "\x1b[31m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_GREEN   "\x1b[32m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW  "\x1b[33m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_BLUE    "\x1b[34m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_MAGENTA "\x1b[35m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_CYAN    "\x1b[36m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_RESET   "\x1b[0m"

using namespace std;



void main_header()
{
     printf (ANSI_COLOR_GREEN  "+---------------+---------------¦ " ANSI_COLOR_RESET  "\n");
     printf (ANSI_COLOR_GREEN  "+---------" ANSI_COLOR_RED " THE GENERAL "  "---------¦" ANSI_COLOR_RESET  "\n");
     printf (ANSI_COLOR_GREEN  "+---------------+---------------¦ " ANSI_COLOR_RESET  "\n");
}

int main()
{
    main_header();
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am using Bloodshed to compile the program. After I have complied the program I upload it via FTP and execute `dos2unix main.cpp` . I then try and run the program but I get this error:

```
./main.cpp: line 12: using: command not found
./main.cpp: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./main.cpp: line 16: `void main_header()'
```

I have no idea why this error is appearing. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: remove `system("pause")`, too

Comment: You get that error when you try to run? Surely it's a compiler error. Tell us more about how you're compiling it with Bloodshed.

Comment: Ummm you have to compile it for or on the target machine before you can execute it. You can't simply run the .cpp files like they are scripts.

Comment: *"./main.cpp"* Wait, why does  your source file have an "executable" filemode in the first place?

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Most likely because `main.cpp` is located on a FAT file system which doesn't have file modes, and thus the effective filemode is determined by the mount options. And clearly those mount options did not include `noexec`.

Comment: @MSalters Ok, this would make sense. Thanks.

Comment: `dos2unix` is (almost certainly) not relevant to this. The c++ compiler shouldn't mind what format the text is in

Comment: @MSalters I would have guessed it's the default file mode in their FTP client.

Comment: @AndyG While you're at it - forget you ever heard that `system("pause")` exists.  I can't believe they still teach that in schools these days, it's absolutely the worst way to put a pause at the end of your program.  Try `getchar()` or `cin.get()` instead.

Comment: There's no need to `#include <iostream>` if you are going to use **printf(3)** to do the actual output from the program.

Comment: the errors you post here are because of trying to execute the source code as a shell script.  Don't know why is this happening, but probably because some error on the compiling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of compiling and running the code, you are running the source code directly.

What you want to do instead is the following:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main
./main
```

Answer (score 2):

You still need to compile the program on Linux!

On Linux `#` is the shell script comment character, so the first line interpreted as a shell command is `using namespace std`.